# How to find maximum value and its reference name from hive table?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a hive table "airline" like this:

```
name     airline
USA      American Airline
Nepal    Jet Airline
Dubai    Emirates
USA      SouthWestern
USA      Quatar
USA      Delta
```

Now, I wanted to know which country have highest number of airlines.
I am using nested subqueries.

```
select max(tot)
from
(select name as countryName, count(airline) as tot
from airline
group by name) a
```

This gives the maximum count of airline which in this case is 4.

```
4
```

But I also need the country name. So,the desired output is:

```
USA 4
```

How can we do it using subqueries? I have done it without using subqueries. I need to execute using subqueries. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select a.*
from (select name as countryName, count(airline) as tot,
             row_number() over (order by count(airline) desc) as seqnum
      from airline
      group by name
     ) a
where seqnum = 1;
```

In the case of ties, this gives one arbitrary country.  If you want all, just change the `row_number()` to `rank()`.

Comment: Can we use another subquery to determine maximum value and name without ordering?

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  But if you have another question, you should ask it as a question rather than in a comment.

Comment: I mean to say that, cannot we find the maximum value and name without using order  and desc functions. I am thinking of solving using only nested queries. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could do somthing like thes:

```
select name, max(tot)
from
(select name as countryName, count(airline) as tot
from airline
group by name) a
```

Comment: This expression will give error like:
SemanticException [Error 10025]: Line 1:7 Expression not in GROUP BY key 'name'

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for nesting.

```
select country, count(*) as tot
      from airline
      group by country
order by tot desc
limit 1
```

Comment: I have done this way but I also need using subquery. How can I do it using subquery.

Answer (score -1):

its very easy just try the form below to get max value :
SELECT MAX(column_name) FROM table_name;

Comment: I also need the name not just max value.

Comment: SELECT column_name
 FROM table_name
 ORDER BY column_name ASC or DESC as you like try it its work